# How can I configure usemin for multiple targets?

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-usemin

I need to configure my Gruntfile to process multiple frontend directories. Currently, I have it setup as follows:

```
main
--assets
----js
vnext
--assets
----js
Gruntfile.js
```

My current usemin/useminPrepare configuration is:

```
useminPrepare: {
  main:{
    src: ['main/index.html'],
    options:{
     dest: 'dist/main',
     staging: '.tmp/main'}},
  vnext:{
    src: ['vnext/index.html'],
    options:{
     dest: 'dist/vnext'
     staging: '.tmp/vnext'}}
},
usemin:{
  html: ['dist/**/index.html']
}
```

However, the issue is that when I run the useminPrepare task, the second target (vnext) adds its files to the source of first target.
Is there any way for useminPrepare to keep things separate?

Comment: Can you add your build block from html and grunt task that you are running?